# Node-opcua interoperability issue. How to solve?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-opcua

I am running into an issue with the node-opcua library. We use the library to set up a client that connects anonymously on a Kepware Server (v6).

App is working fine in debug and in production on various servers but seems to be unable to create a session on a specific server we are trying to install it on.

What makes me think it is an interoperability issue is that when we first installed the app on the server, it made another app(Cimplicity) that feeds the Kepware Server to crash.

The app is an electron app using node-opcua latest. The "problematic server" is a VM with Microsoft Server 2019.

**Here is my opcua service code** :

```
const opcua = require("node-opcua");
const path = require("path");
let conf = global.conf;
const { ipcMain } = require("electron");
const log = require("electron-log");

const options = {
  applicationName: "Ganex OPC UA Server",
  connectionStrategy: opcua.connectionStrategy,
  securityMode: opcua.MessageSecurityMode.None,
  securityPolicy: opcua.SecurityPolicy.None,
  endpoint_must_exist: false,
};

class OPCUAService {
  eventEmitter;

  static setEventEmitter(eventEmitterObj) {
    this.eventEmitter = eventEmitterObj;

    this.eventEmitter.on("updatedAuthentication", () => {
      // config = require("../config/configUrl");//in theory should get the new config from file if its updated
      console.log("Updated Conf?", conf.get("auth:opcUrl"));
    });
  }

  static async readData(addressArray) {
    const client = opcua.OPCUAClient.create();
    const endpointUrl = conf.get("auth:opcUrl");
    const opcUserName = conf.get("auth:opcServerUserName");
    const opcPassword = conf.get("auth:opcServerPassword");

    client.on("backoff", () => {
      console.log("backoff");
      globalThis.connected = false;
      log.info("Error connecting to OPC Server", "Can't access the OPC Server");
    });

    client.on("connected", () => (globalThis.connected = true));

    if (globalThis.connected) {
      log.info("OPC Server is accessible? ", globalThis.connected);
    }

    try {
      console.log("Start!");
      log.info("Connecting to OPC");
      //var userIdentityInfo = new usr
      await client.connect(endpointUrl);
      //const session = await client.createSession({});
      //const session = await client.createSession({userName: opcUserName, password: opcPassword});
      /* const session = await client.createSession({}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          log.info("Error at session creation", err);
        } else {
          log.info("Session successfully created", err);
        }
      }); */

      const session = await client.createSession({});
      log.info("Session created? ", session? "true" : "false");
      log.info ("Session Content", addressArray);
      console.log("Session Content", addressArray);

      for (let count = 0; count < addressArray.length; count++) {
        const readResult = await session.read({
          nodeId: addressArray[count].address,
          attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value,
        });
        addressArray[count].value = parseFloat(
          readResult.value.toString().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, "")
        ).toFixed(addressArray[count].precision);
      }

      await session.close();
      log.info("Disconnected from OPC");

      await client.disconnect();

      return addressArray;
    } catch (err) {
      log.info("Error connecting to OPC Server", err);
      log.error(err.toString());
      console.log("Err =", err);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = OPCUAService;
```

It seems that the problem is at the session creation level. Here is an extract of log from a **working** server :

```
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.004] [info] @@@ running processSolarFacilityMetData Task every 1 minute(s)
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.111] [info] OPC Server is accessible?  true
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.144] [info] Connecting to OPC
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.174] [info] @@@ running processPowerData Task every 1 minute(s)
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.191] [info] OPC Server is accessible?  true
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.236] [info] Connecting to OPC
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.605] [info] Session created?  true
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.608] [info] Session Content [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.627] [info] Session created?  true
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.637] [info] Session Content [object Object],[object Object]
[2021-12-20 08:03:00.765] [info] Disconnected from OPC
[2021-12-20 08:03:01.381] [info] Disconnected from OPC
```

and one from the **problematic** server

```
Starting up application @ C:\Program Files\Forecast Compliance...
[2021-12-20 06:31:12.280] [info]
[2021-12-20 06:31:14.814] [info] solarFacilityData: undefined
[2021-12-20 06:32:00.001] [info] @@@ running processPowerData Task every 1 minute(s)
[2021-12-20 06:32:00.011] [info] Connecting to OPC
[2021-12-20 06:32:00.020] [info] @@@ running processSolarFacilityMetData Task every 1 minute(s)
[2021-12-20 06:32:00.022] [info] Connecting to OPC
[2021-12-20 06:33:00.006] [info] @@@ running processPowerData Task every 1 minute(s)
[2021-12-20 06:33:00.013] [info] Connecting to OPC
[2021-12-20 06:33:00.017] [info] @@@ running processSolarFacilityMetData Task every 1 minute(s)
[2021-12-20 06:33:00.019] [info] Connecting to OPC
[2021-12-20 06:34:00.002] [info] @@@ running processSolarFacilityMetData Task every 1 minute(s)
[2021-12-20 06:34:00.003] [info] Connecting to OPC
[2021-12-20 06:34:00.005] [info] @@@ running processPowerData Task every 1 minute(s)
```

Does anyone has a clue on how to solve that kind of issues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the connect method is not returning

```
await client.connect(endpointUrl);
```

In case of an unreachable server we would expect a backoff event to be raised on a regular basis to indicate that the connect function is retrying failed connection. we don't have this.

Also, you have a try/catch block and no error message, this leads me think that something is happening either on the socket or on the server side.

This case would require deeper investigation offline. I would recommend contacting the node-opcua support team ( see website for more info).

Disclaimer, I am the author of the node-opcua library.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I'll contact you through your web site. Thx!